# Writing an event as a disjoint union of events - $\bigcup A\cap B_i$ or $\bigcup A|B_i$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am having trouble with two ways of writing an event as a disjoint union of events - as the union of $A\cap B_i$ or $A|B_i$.

For example:

Say we have a bag with $a$ blue balls, $b$ red balls and $c$ yellow balls and we take them out of the bag one by one without returning. We want to find the probability that the blue balls are all out of the bag first.

Say $A_1$ is the event the blue balls are all out of the bag first, $B_2$ the event the red balls are all out second, $C_3$ the yellow balls are all out third, $B_3$- red balls third, $C_2$- yellow balls second.

I know the probability of one kind of the balls to stay last is the initial number of balls of this color devided by the initial number of all balls in the bag. So I want to express $P(A_1)$ in terms of $P(B_3)$ and $P(C_3)$. (calculated beforehand)

Now, should I write $P(A_1)=P(A_1\cap B_3)+P(A_1\cap C_3)$ (since $A_1$ is the disjoint union of $A_1\cap B_3$ and $A_1\cap C_3$ - those give us the information about what happened), or perhaps $P(A_1)=P(A_1|B_3)+P(A_1|C_3)$ since $A_1$ is the disjoint union of $A_1$ happening if $B_3$ happens and $A_1$ happening if $C_3$ happens. But of course these are not equal since $P(A\cap B)=P(A|B)P(B)$, so one of the unions I wrote isn't correct. Why? I don't see the difference between these two ways. Can someone please clear the confusion?

Comment: The second is wrong.  Suppose $a=b=c=1$, one of each color.  Then, by symmetry, $P(A_1\,|\,B_3)=.5=P(A_1\,|\,C_3)$   But $P(A_1)≠1$ (actually, it is $\frac 13$).

Comment: Thanks for the example, but what's the logic behind it being wrong? Why doesn't it make sense to say A is the union of A happening if B happens and A happening if C happens?

Comment: It's hard to add conditional probabilities...they take place in different sample spaces.  As, a perhaps clearer example, suppose $a=b=1$ and $c=0$.  Then $P(A_1)=.5$.  This clearly does equal $P(A_1\cap B_2)$ (as the events $A_1,B_2$ coincide) but $P(A_1\,|B_2)=1$.

Comment: So if I write $P(A_1)=P(A_1\cap B_3)+P(A_1\cap C_3)=P(A_1|B_3)P(B_3)+P(A_1|C_3)P(C_3)$, how do I calculate $P(A_1|B_3)$ and $P(A_1|C_3)$?..

Comment: If you know that, say, the $B$ balls leave last then either $A$ or $C$ goes first.  Ignore the selection of the $B$ balls, we already know about them.  Of the others, what's the probability that the last one is a $C$?

Comment: I would say $\frac c{a+c}$, but... I don't know how many $B$ balls are taken out before they are the only ones left...

Comment: Doesn't matter about the $B$ balls. Since we are given that they go last, the only question is how the $A's$ and $C's$ are distributed relative to each other.  The exact moments the $B's$ are removed has no impact on that.  Your answer is correct.

Comment: I get it. Thank you so much! This was very helpful :)

Comment: Even your first equation is not correct. There should be an extra term $P(A_1\cap \bar B_3 ~ \cap \bar C_3)$ on RHS.

Comment: I would say draw a venn diagram with three events $A_1, B_3, C_3$. You'll figure it out yourself.

Comment: More drastically than the above: If A and B are events, then A|B is not an event, in fact A|B *does not exist* at all.